# How to implement common data sharing between individual JUnit Testcases

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have three test cases namely `Test1.java`, `Test2.java`, `Test3.java`. In every testcase i am interacting with one file about to read the data.
Which means i am reading the file data in `@BeforeClass` of every testcase and unloading the same data in `@AfterClass` of every testcase.

So now my requirement is that, i wanted to do file read operation before executing the those 3 testcases and the same data should be able to share among those 3 testcases while executing them.

Currently i have implemented below:

```
public class Test1{
private File testFile;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpFiledata() {
        // Code for reading the file data
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownFiledata() {
        // Code for unloading the file data
    }
}

public class Test2{
private File testFile;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpFiledata() {
        // Code for reading the file data
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownFiledata() {
        // Code for unloading the file data
    }
}

public class Test3{
private File testFile;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpFiledata() {
        // Code for reading the file data
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownFiledata() {
        // Code for unloading the file data
    }
}
```

In the above code, every testcase has a `@BeforeClass` & `@AfterClass` methods to initialize the file which is common for every testcase. Now i require a way which can share the file content in every testcase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use test suite to run these tests, and use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` on the test suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Test1.class, Test2.class, Test3.class})
public class MySuite {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpFiledata() {
        // Code for reading the file data
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownFiledata() {
        // Code for unloading the file data
    }
}
```